# Spring Controller waits for async response instad of managing the next request

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have this request endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/verify")
public Callable<String> verify() {
    logger.debug("----STARTED REQUEST-----");
    Callable<String> callable = () -> {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        logger.debug("_____FINISHED REQUEST_____");
        return "foo";
    };
    logger.debug("FREED CONTROLLER");
    return callable;
}
```

It returns a `Callable` object, that sleeps for 5 seconds.

My **Goal**: When I have multiple incomming requests I want them to be handled asynchronously.

What I mean is that when the first request comes and I return a callable object, then the controller, in the **meantime of waiting**, should handle the next request. But instead it waits for the callable to complete and only then handles the next request. Here is the log.

```
[nio-8080-exec-1] c.t.c.lol.task.TaskLolController         : ----STARTED REQUEST-----
[nio-8080-exec-1] c.t.c.lol.task.TaskLolController         : FREED CONTROLLER
[      MvcAsync1] c.t.c.lol.task.TaskLolController         : _____FINISHED REQUEST_____
[nio-8080-exec-3] c.t.c.lol.task.TaskLolController         : ----STARTED REQUEST-----
[nio-8080-exec-3] c.t.c.lol.task.TaskLolController         : FREED CONTROLLER
[      MvcAsync2] c.t.c.lol.task.TaskLolController         : _____FINISHED REQUEST_____
[nio-8080-exec-5] c.t.c.lol.task.TaskLolController         : ----STARTED REQUEST-----
[nio-8080-exec-5] c.t.c.lol.task.TaskLolController         : FREED CONTROLLER
[      MvcAsync3] c.t.c.lol.task.TaskLolController         : _____FINISHED REQUEST_____
```

What I want:

```
----STARTED REQUEST-----
FREED CONTROLLER
----STARTED REQUEST-----
FREED CONTROLLER
----STARTED REQUEST-----
FREED CONTROLLER
_____FINISHED REQUEST_____
_____FINISHED REQUEST_____
_____FINISHED REQUEST_____
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please provide your MVC configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service from your `callable` method

```
@Service
private class TaskService {
    @Async
    public String execute() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            LOGGER.debug("_____FINISHED REQUEST_____");
            return "foo";
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

}
```

In your controller, define the callable to be the execute method of your `TaskService``

```
@Autowired
TaskService taskService;

@PostMapping("/verify")
public Callable<String> verify() {
    Callable<String> callable = taskservice::execute;

    logger.debug("FREED CONTROLLER");
    return callable;
}
```

@edit
To make `@Async` annotation work I need to enable async:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return Executors.newWorkStealingPool(); //will use as many threads as your processor has
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but only if I add `@Async` annotation to `TaskService.execute` method.

Comment: Well, in fact it logs properly, but when I send a request I immediately get empty response without waiting.

Answer (score -3):

You use Thread in the `verify`，for example:

```
Thread thread =  new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                System.out.println("Callable");
            }

        };
        thread.start();
```

Comment: Ok, but then the controller won't wait for the response.